# Trying to create multiple counters using Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, counter

I can create one counter very easy with this example.  How do I use this multiple times on one page?

```
<div>
    You've clicked <span data-bind="text: numberOfClicks"></span> times
    <button data-bind="click: incrementClickCounter">Click me</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        numberOfClicks : ko.observable(0),
        incrementClickCounter : function() {
            var previousCount = this.numberOfClicks();
            this.numberOfClicks(previousCount + 1);
        }
    };
</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In that case you can make use of javascript closures.

```
function Counter(){
    var self = this;
     self.numberOfClicks = ko.observable(0);
     self.incrementClickCounter = function() {
        self.numberOfClicks(self.numberOfClicks() + 1);
    };
}

var viewModel = {
     counter1: new Counter(),
     counter2: new Counter()
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/marcandrew/wckE2/

Comment: Is there a way to keep the value so when the page is refreshed I don't the numbers of "clicks"?

Comment: I didn't ask the question right.  I need the counters to store the values so visitor see the counters increase over time.

Comment: You'll have to stored it in local storage or a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you mean by using this multiple times on one page?
Do you want all of the instances to share the amount of times clicked or should they be independent of each other?

If they are just sharing it then you can just bind multiple elements to the same click event.

```
<div>
    You've clicked <span data-bind="text: numberOfClicks"></span> times
    <button data-bind="click: incrementClickCounter">Click me</button>
    <button data-bind="click: incrementClickCounter">Click me Too</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I need them independent of each other.